# Passing a JSON object from Flask to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, google-maps, flask, jinja2

I'm having troubles getting a Flask/Python variable passed to Javascript.

Basically, I'm importing from MySQL and have tried rendering the return in three different ways.

1. `(43.8934276, -103.3690243), (47.052060, -91.639868), (45.1118, -95.0396)` that is the output when my dict item has the following ran on it.

`new_list = [tuple(d.values()) for d in MySQL_Dict]
 output = ', '.join('(' + ', '.join(i) + ')' for i in new_list)`

This method is no good, but I added it for detail, it's not in the right format at all.

2. I pass the python dict directly to the template which looks like this

`({'lat': '43.8934276', 'lng': '-103.3690243'}, {'lat': '47.052060', 'lng': '-91.639868'}, {'lat': '45.1118', 'lng': '-95.0396'})`

Then on the the template side I've tried the following JavaScript lines

```
 var other_coords = {{ MySQL_Dict|tojson }}; 
 var other_coords = {{ MySQL_Dict|tojson|safe }};
 var still_more = JSON.parse(other_coords);
```

None of which work, together or separately.

3. I've also tried sending the dictionary from the view using `json_out = json.dumps(My_Dict)` which does not work either.

This is all with the goal of getting the lat, lng coords from the MySQL DB to the Google Maps API script. The thing that is so confusing to me is that if I just paste the json.dump results from the view into the Google Maps script it works perfectly (after the quotes are removed) but if I use a variable it will not work for me. Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: What is the desired output in the rendered HTML?

Comment: Markers on a Google Map.

Comment: Sorry I mean what output format (coordinates) are you looking for?

Comment: Oh sorry, it needs to look like this, just a JavaScript object, correct? Which I thought you could get from JSON by using the JSON.parse(json_object)?

[{lat: 43.8934276, lng: -103.3690243}, {lat: 47.052060, lng: -91.639868}, {lat: 45.1118, lng: -95.0396}]

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It seems that the currently accepted answer (by @BrettJ) has a possible security flaw in it: if the object we pass to javascript has some string with a single quote inside, this single quote will not be escaped by `json.dumps`, thus allowing to inject arbitrary code into javascript. It is better to use Flask's `tojson()` template filter, see [the docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/templating/#standard-filters), as it makes proper escaping of all such characters (replace them with unicode codes).

Here is my solution:

**view.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    user = {'firstname': "Mr.", 'lastname': "My Father's Son"}
    return render_template("index.html", user=user)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**index.html**

```
<p>Hello, <span id="username"></span></p>
<script>
    var user = JSON.parse('{{ user | tojson | safe}}');
    document.getElementById('username').innerHTML = user.firstname + " " +
            user.lastname;
</script>
```

Generated JS looks like:

```
var user = JSON.parse('{"firstname": "Mr.", "lastname": "My Father\u0027s Son"}');
```

which is perfectly safe. For example, if we'd use `json.dumps`-powered solution, we'd get

```
var user = JSON.parse('{"firstname": "Mr.", "lastname": "My Father's Son"}');
```

which is syntactically incorrect (to say the least).

Comment: Your answer works for me. I changed my accepted answer, better security always equals better code.

Comment: Thank you very much! You saved me a lot of time! :)

Comment: This line `JSON.parse('{{ user | tojson | safe}}')` was exactly what I needed. The single-quotes helped too!

Comment: I'm curious to get clarity about the security vulnerability point raised by @Ilya V. Schurov ("this single quote will not be escaped by json.dumps, thus allowing to inject arbitrary code into javascript"). You are pointing out that the vulnerability is that the unescaped code passed by json dumps itself can itself be code injectable into javascript. Correct?

Comment: @hbrannan yes, the intruder can put malicious javascript code into fields that they set (i.e. user name during registration, or message text, or something else), and this code can steal cookies/sessions, etc.

Comment: There is no need to put the output of `tojson` into quotes and then parse them as JSON. **JSON is already a valid Javascript literal.** Just `var user = {{ user | tojson | safe }};` is just fine.

Comment: @deceze yes, I didn't think about it. And with your solution, do we still get the vulnurability with `json.dumps` approach instead of `| tojson`? It seems that double quote will be properly escaped by `json.dumps` and no arbitrary code injection is possible. Am I correct? Anyway, it seems we need a new answer to upvote and accept :)

Answer (score 4):

The below simple example should show how to get a Javascript object from your dict:

**views.py**

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])                                         
def index():                                                                    

    points = [{"lat": 43.8934276, "lng": -103.3690243},                         
              {"lat": 47.052060, "lng": -91.639868},                            
              {"lat": 45.1118, "lng": -95.0396}]                                

    return render_template("index.html", points=json.dumps(points))
```

**index.html** (some code removed for brevity)

```
  function initMap() {                                                      

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {         
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.8934276, -103.3690243),             
      zoom: 4                                                               
    });                                                                     

    var points = JSON.parse('{{ points|safe }}');                           
    var marker;                                                             

    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {                               

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({                                   
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(points[i].lat, points[i].lng),   
          map: map                                                          
        });                                                                 

    }                                                                       
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Ok, so why is this happening? If I do everything as you say the markers do not appear on the map. In Google Maps I'm just setting `var locations = points;` However, if I copy and paste the output of the points var defined by you, and do `var locations = [{lat: 43.8934276,lng: -103.3690243 },{lat: 47.05206,lng: -91.639868}, {lat:45.1118,lng: -95.0396 }]` directly into the maps script it works perfect!... I'm so confused.

Comment: I have added some sample Javascript for rendering the markers on the map. Tested locally and it renders the markers for me. Hope this helps!

Comment: You sir are a god! Thank you so much. My biggest issue all this time was actual map script itself... how disappointing. Thanks a ton!!

Comment: Also, note to self and/or future people with this issue. I had an underscore in my variable which JS didn't appreciate. Once I changed that, things worked much better. I never write JS so I'm not sure if this is a rule or syntax issue or what. Anyway, thanks again Matt.

Comment: There is a security issue in this solution (possible arbitrary javascript code injection) due to the lack of escaping of single quote character. It is better to use `tojson` Flask template filter. See my answer for details.