# Unexpected token { in JSON while passing data from flask to javascript

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I am trying to pass simple data from flask to javascript file 
I am following this answer
[Passing a JSON object from Flask to JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42499535/passing-a-json-object-from-flask-to-javascript)

But i got Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse ()

```
var user = JSON.parse('{{ data | tojson}}');      
 var grade=user.grade;
 console.log(grade);
```

my python file have code

```
@app.route("/quiz/0")
def quizFirst():
    data={"grade":"0"}
    return render_template('quiz.html',data=data)
```

the token { is not recognizable by javascript in js file, Any idea what i am missing.

Comment: is the JavaScript inside `quiz.html` or is it in a separate .js file?

Comment: js file is a separate file,not inside quiz.html

Comment: Well this will always fail `var user = JSON.parse('{{ data | tojson}}'); ` I don't know if maybe that's meant to get replaced somehow, but as written it will literally try to parse that string. So JSON.parse sees `{{` and immediately errors.

Comment: so placing javascript inside is an only option, so wil i able to communicate with my js file which is seperate file?

Comment: Well I figured it out, any variable inside javascript  in HTML file can be accessible to external(separate) js file, provided that variable is declared before its use, for that link to seperate file must be below the html javascript

Comment: What if I want to access the data inside render_template from a javaScript that is not in the html document but in static/app.js

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works for me. This JavaScript needs to be inside `quiz.html`. The reason is that Flask will process `quiz.html` and replace `{{ data | tojson }}` with the data provided in `render_template`. However, it won't process your static JS file.

#### quiz.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>sotest</title>
</head>
<body>

  Hello World!

<script>
  var user = JSON.parse('{{ data | tojson}}');      
  var grade=user.grade;
  console.log(grade);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

#### app.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/quiz/0")
def quizFirst():
    data={"grade":"0"}
    return render_template('quiz.html',data=data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```