# Python Flask pass strings from backend to JavaScript

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I use this template to pass values from Flask to the frontend (chart)

```
@app.route("/allusers", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def allusers():
    if request.method == "GET":
        user_collection = mongo.db.users
        df = pd.DataFrame(list(user_collection.find()))
        df["price"] = df["price"].apply(pd.to_numeric)
        result = round(df["price"].mean(), 2)
        return render_template(
            "/result.html",
            result=result,
            nrow=df.shape[0],
            series=list(df["price"]),
            description=list(df["description"]),
        )
```

The price values give work perfectly fine, but the strings which I `console.log`

```
{{description}}
```

in the HTML gives me this:

```
['dfsf', 'dfsfggg', 'dfsf', 'dfsdfs']

console.log("{{description}}");
```

This gives me:

```
[&#39;dfsf&#39;, &#39;dfsfggg&#39;, &#39;dfsf&#39;, &#39;dfsdfs&#39;]
```

I have to use it in JS like this:

```
  <script>
    $(function() {
      console.log("{{description}}");

      $("#container").highcharts({
        chart: {
          animation: {
            duration: 1000
          }
        },

        xAxis: {
          categories: ["Bla", "bla2", "bla3", "Bla4"]
        },

        series: [
          {
            data: JSON.parse("{{series}}"),
            name: "Price"
          }
        ]
      });
    });
  </script>
```

The strings seem to get converted somehow. Can anyone tell me what happens there and what I can do about it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unexpected token { in JSON while passing data from flask to javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49241455/unexpected-token-in-json-while-passing-data-from-flask-to-javascript)

Comment: that comes closer, but it does still not work:

`JSON.parse("["dfsf", "dfsfggg", "dfsf", "dfsdfs"]");` is the result

Comment: JSON will always use double quotes, try enclosing the string using single quotes to avoid requiring the need to escape those double quotes, i.e. `JSON.parse('{{ series | tojson }}')`, like how it is in the answer linked.

Comment: thank you,... i did not see this, my "prettier" extension recodes single quotes to double quotes >_<

Comment: *＋1* for keeping the site tidy.