# How to loop over a list from Flask in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I'm trying to pass in a list from a database from Flask, into Javascript to make Google Maps api markers.
For example, from Flask, I'm passing to home.html a list of cars and their longitude and latitude. I then want to loop over this list, and create a google map marker for each location and put it on the map.

```
function placeCars() {
        {% for cars in car_locations %}
        var position = {
            lat: cars.Location.Latitude,
            lng: cars.Location.Longitude
        };
        new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map
      });
        {% endfor %}
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
{{cars.Location.longitude}}
```

You should wrap it in `{{ }}`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you're encountering is flask will create a function in the html that looks like this:

```
function placeCars() {
  var position = {
      lat: 123,
      lng: 456
  };
  new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      map: map
  });
  var position = {
      lat: 789,
      lng: 123
  };
  new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      map: map
  });
}
```

Then you would need another piece of javascript to execute that function call

Try changing your javascript to something like this

```
  // Load the data from Flask
  var carLocations = JSON.parse('{{ car_locations | tojson | safe }}');

  // When the page has loaded iterate through your list using javascript
  // and pass the values to your function 
  (function() {
    carLocations.forEach(car => placeCars(car));
  })();

  function placeCars(nextPosition) {
    var position = {
      lat: nextPosition.Location.Latitude,
      lng: nextPosition.Location.Longitude
    };
    new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      map: map
    });
  }
```

See this answer for passing json data to your template: [Passing a JSON object from Flask to JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42499535/passing-a-json-object-from-flask-to-javascript)

Comment: This looked like it would work, thanks. Just getting an error "TypeError: Object of type CarLocations is not JSON serializable", will do a bit of investigating