# Passing JSON data from Flask to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask

I am trying to pass a JSON data from flask to JavaScript.

The code I tried is from:

- [Passing a JSON object from Flask to JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42499535/passing-a-json-object-from-flask-to-javascript)

---

The steps below are what I did :

1. I first got my data from postgreSQL in Python
2. I transformed the data format from DataFrame to JSON

```
    
def to_json2(df,orient='split'):
    df_json = df.to_json(orient = orient, force_ascii = False)
    return json.loads(df_json)


def to_fronrend(data):
    return {"data": data}

json2 = to_json2(df)
json2 = to_fronrend(json2)
```

3. I modified @Ilya V. Schurov's code

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')

def hello_world():
    data = json2
    return render_template("index.html", data = data)

app.run()
```

And this is my index.html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> Hello </title>
</head>
    
<body>
    <p>Hello, <span id="username"></span></p>
    
    <script>
    var data = JSON.parse('{{ json2 | tojson | safe}}');
    document.getElementById('username').innerHTML = data.Name + " " + data.Gatein;
    </script>

    
    </body>
</html>
```

---

However, it kept showing the error

```
TypeError: Object of type Undefined is not JSON serializable
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Dec/2020 22:14:14] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

And the webpage(http://127.0.0.1:5000/) showing:

```
Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

I spent almost 2 days on this problem, passing the json data to the JavaScript, but still don't know how to solve this... Could anyone give me some suggestion on this?

Comment: I guess you tried to add a link in the first paragraph but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Are you using jinja2 with flask?

Comment: @Tahirhan thanks for reminding! I have edited the link :)

Comment: @Jay I don't think so (?)

Comment: Like alecxe says, `{{ data | tojson | safe }}` (the template engine doesn't know what `json2` is)

Comment: @ChrisG It works!! Thank you and Alecxe. Actually, I tried this before but at that time I was facing another question, which is the data sent to the webpage is wrong. When I open the webpage, it shows "Hello, undefined undefined" <-- I am not sure is this caused by my html file or it was caused by my python file :(

Comment: Check your HTML source code in the browser (Ctrl+U). Looking at `to_fronrend` you can probably skip that call altogether; my guess is you have `{ "data": { "Name": "abc" } }` in there and would have to use `data.data.Name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the template, you are using the variable `json2`:

```
{{ json2 | tojson | safe}}
```

but, when rendering, you are passing in variable `data`:

```
return render_template("index.html", data=data)
```

Replace `json2` with `data` in your template:

```
{{ data | tojson | safe }}
```

Comment: Ohh yes, sorry I did try this before and it works! But the thing is, when I use {{ data | tojson | safe }} <-- it seems like the data cannot be sent correctly to the webpage. I mean, it always show "Hello, undefined undefined" on the webpage.

Comment: Should I check my HTML file or it was caused by the python code?

Comment: @Agnes try debugging it more: e.g. one thing you could do is to print out the value of `data` variable inside the `hello_world` function. Do you see `Name` and `Gatein` keys printed? Also, check for case-sensitivity.