# Passing a JSON from Python to JS and declaring it

Tags: javascript, python, json

For a website, I'm calling a helper function (the python code) which returns 2 values, a Python dict and a JSON. When I pass the JSON to JS I get: referenceError: js_dictionary is not defined.

```
    test_dictionary = dict()
    for key in words:
        test_dictionary.update({key: dictionary[key]})
    js_test_dictionary = json.dumps(test_dictionary)
    return test_dictionary, js_test_dictionary
```

```
return render_template("study.html", language=selected, dictionary=dictionary, js_dictionary=js_dictionary)
```

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const dictionary = `${js_dictionary}`;
    const translations = JSON.parse(dictionary);
    document.querySelector('#check').onclick = function() {
```

I have tried using jQuery instead of JSON.parse and have tried formatting js_dictionary with/without "$``". Any help would go a long way!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42499535/passing-a-json-object-from-flask-to-javascript

Comment: note : change `test_dictionary.update({key: dictionary[key]})` to `test_dictionary[key] = dictionary[key]`